# How are gymnastics routines scored?

Tags: olympics, scoring, gymnastics

In scoring routines in gymnastics, there is "theoretically no limit to the score a gymnast can achieve." However, the highest score judges can award for the execution of a routine is 10. Furthermore, "17" and "perfect 10" are often synonymous.

Given the former, has a score greater than 7 ever been awarded for the difficulty of a gymnast's routine? If theoretically possible, how does a gymnast's routine accomplish this?

---

A summary of the scoring system in gymnastics:

- A panel of judges score the execution of the routine. This score starts at 10 and decreases with each deductable instance, such as taking a step when landing a dismount or falling off a balance beam.
- Another panel of judges score the difficulty of the routine. This score starts at 0 and increases with every skill/combination performed.

A sample routine score:

[image: Sample Routine Score]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've covered most of the points but I'll try to add a bit of explanation around them now.

The scoring system is governed by the [Code of Points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_of_Points_%28artistic_gymnastics%29).

The codes were overhauled in 2006 (following controversy in the 2004 games).  Previously, perfect 10 was the best that a gymnast could score.

Using the new code:

10 is the absolute maximum that can be awarded for **execution**.  The judges start at 10 and then deduct an amount for each error such as wobbles, balance issues, extra footsteps etc.

- Small errors have a 0.1 deduction
- Medium errors have a 0.3 deduction
- Large errors have a 0.5 deduction
- Falling from a piece of apparatus has a 1.0 deduction.

In addition to the execution (E) score, there is a separate panel of judges scoring the **difficulty** (D) score.  This comprises of three elements: Difficulty Value (DV), Composition Requirements (CR) and Connection Value (CV).

> The D-score (or Difficulty score) evaluates the content of the exercise on three criteria: the Difficulty Value (DV), Composition Requirements (CR) and Connection Value (CV).
>
> - DV: The difficulty value of the eight highest value elements of the routine, including the dismount, are added together. Elements are ranked depending on their difficulty; for example on beam, a back layout salto to two feet is given a difficulty of E, and a back layout salto with a full twist is given a difficulty of G. For a G skill a gymnast earns 0.7; for an E, he or she earns 0.5 points.
> - CR: Gymnasts must demonstrate skills from five required Element Groups on each apparatus. A gymnast may use skills to fulfill the DV and the CR simultaneously. For each CR presented, 0.5 points are awarded. A maximum score of 2.50 points may be earned here.
> - CV: Additional points are given for connections of two or more elements of specific value, with 0.1 or 0.2 points apiece.

So, with that scoring system, there is no upper-limit to the number of points that a gymnast can accumulate on the D-score.

As for gymnasts who have scored (or attempted to score) more than 7.0, I can think of the following:

- [Li Shanshan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li_Shanshan), whose difficulty rating was 7.3 on the beam
- [Nastia Liukin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nastia_Liukin), who has an uneven bars routine of 7.7 and scored 17.1 with it in the 2008 Visa Championships

If you fancy trying Liukin's routine yourself(!) it is:

Glide kip cast to HS (KCHS), Stalder shoot to HB (Ray); KCHS, Pike stalder 1/2 to eagle grip, Eagle endo, Ono, Healy, Ono 1/2, Gienger; KCHS, Pike stalder, Tkachev; KCHS, Pak salto; KCHS 1/2, Toe shoot to HB; KCHS, Giant 1/2 to eagle, double front 1/2 dismount

Comment: Liukin's routine is the only score over 17 in that [competition](http://www.gymnasticsresults.com/2008/uschampw1.html), and it could have been a 17.7! Astonishing!

Comment: @edmastermind29 - It's phenomenal, really!